# Access HTTP response when using Jersey client proxy

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-client

I'm using Jersey 2.22 to consume a REST api.
The approach is contract-first, a service interface and wrappers are used to call the REST api (using org.glassfish.jersey.client.proxy package).

> WebClient webClient = ClientBuilder.newClient();
>   WebTarget webTarget = webClient.getWebTarget(endPoint);
>   ServiceClass proxy = WebResourceFactory.newResource(ServiceClass.class, webTarget);
>   Object returnedObject = proxy.serviceMethod("id1");

The question is: how to get the underlying HTTP response (HTTP status + body)?
When the returnedObject is null, I need to analyze the response to get error message returned for example.
Is there a way to do it?
I saw that we can plug filters and interceptors to catch the response, but that's not exactly what I need.

Comment: Set up your interface to return `Response`

Comment: I would love to, but I have no control on this interface. And I don't understand why this jersey client proxy doesn't allow access to the underlying response.

Answer (score -1):

You should return [Response](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) as the result of the interface method instead of the plain DTO.

I'm not sure about the level of control you're expecting (considering your reply to @peeskillet comment), but the Response object will give you the opportunity to fine tune your server's response (headers, cookies, status etc.) and read all of them at the client side - as you might see taking a look at Response's members like `getStatus()` and `getHeaders()`.

The only gotcha here is how to get the body. For this, I'd tell you to use `readEntity(Class<T>)` (not the `getEntity()` method as one might try at first). As long as you have the right media type provider registered, you can extract the entity as your DTO class in a easy way.

For example, if you are using maven, jersey and JSON as media type, you can add the following dependency (and take the provider's registration for granted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then, get the entity body deserialized using:

```
Response resp = proxy.serviceMethod("id1");
int status = resp.getStatus();
String statusText = resp.getStatusInfo();
String someHeader = resp.getHeaderString("SOME-HEADER");
YourCustomDTO obj = resp.readEntity(YourCustomDTO.class);
```

When querying a list of your custom objects (i.e. method returns a JSON array) use the array type to read the body.

```
Response resp = proxy.serviceMethodThatReturnsCollection();
YourCustomDTO[] obj = resp.readEntity(YourCustomDTO[].class);
```

Please notice that after reading the body, the stream is closed and trying `getEntity()` may throw an exception.

Hope it helps.